# Formula to edit a cell based on if-else condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am planning to create a cell where if the cells in G2 is empty then it will copy the content from row A but if the cell in column G is updated with something else I dont want to copy the content from row A. I have done code something like this in App Script but it is not working.

```
function getLast(range) {
    var getResult = function(range) {
        if (!((range.getNumRows() > 1 && range.getNumColumns() == 1) || (range.getNumRows() == 1 && range.getNumColumns() > 1))) {
            throw new Error("Please input one row or one column.");
        }
        var v = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], range.getValues());
        var f = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], range.getFormulas());
        var i;
        for (i = v.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (v[i] != "" || f[i] != "") break;
        }
        return i + 1;
    };
    if (Array.isArray(range)) {
        return range.map(function(e) {
            return getResult(e);
        });
    } else {
        try {
            range.getA1Notation();
        } catch (e) {
            throw new Error("Inputted value is not a range.");
        }
        return getResult(range);
    }
}

function formulasheets(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("USERNAMES");
  sheet.getRange("G2").setFormula('=IF(G2="",A2, ');
  var range1 = sheet.getRange("B:B");
  var fillDownRangecolumnI = sheet.getRange(2, 7, lr-1);
  sheet.getRange("G2").copyTo(fillDownRangecolumnA);
}
```

I have attached the image of my google sheet to explain better on what I want. Can ayone help me on this. Thank you.
[image]

```
                                             If Cell G2 & G5 is empty
```

[image]

```
                                        It should be updated with content in row A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your question, and I would like to give a try, hope it is useful for you. Please refer to my edited code below, I think it is better for you to use for loop to check for blank, and to avoid write formula:

```
function formulasheets(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("USERNAMES");
  for (var x=1;x <= sheet.getLastRow();x++){
    var cell = sheet.getRange(x,7);
    if (cell.isBlank()){
      sheet.getRange(x,1).copyTo(cell);
    }
  }
}
```

Before execution
[image]

After execution, accept if help, it is my first time answer G Apps Script :)
[image]

Comment: This is what I want. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Welcome, i like apps script aslo :)